# Node Js Express . how to schedule task

Tags: node.js, express, cron, schedule

How can I schedule a job or task to be executed at a certain point in time?

I have crons for tasks that execute recurrently, but let's say I create a calendar event and I want my server to send a notification whenever it is the time of the event.

Also, will this be deleted whenever the server is restarted? Should I reschedule the job on each startup?

Comment: Can your cron tasks talk to the server? Also, is the notification meant for a web client aka browser?

Comment: Yes, the cron tasks can execute other server fucntions. They notifications are meant for apps and may happen days after the event was generated. I have no problem sending the notification, only scheduling.

Comment: Why not have a cron task checking for events that are due, and send the notifications accordingly? Or if the notif. has to be sent from the server get the cron task to make a request   to the server to do so  with all the details needed.

Comment: Because I didn't think that querying the server for ALL events every hour or minute was the best approach. I was wondering if it was better to simply create a job for each created event independently so that they can live without a cron querying the db.

Comment: If it's from a running server, then just use `setTimeout()`.  When your server restarts, you will have to either rescan the calendar to find things to notify about or you will have to have previously saved in a persistent store the things you want to notify about and can then reload that and set timers for those again.

Comment: I would personally avoid an approach that involves setTimeout on the server at all cost ... smells :)

Comment: @Daniel - Why does `setTimeout()` smell?  If you want to run some task in the context of your server an hour from now, `setTimeout()` is a perfect tool for that.  It's simple and efficient.  Now, I wouldn't architect something that needed thousands of timers as there's probably a more efficient way to use a few timers than thousands (how to do that is application-specific), but otherwise this is exactly what `setTimeout()` is for.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best is [node-schedule](https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule).

and the sample of node-schedule is below:

```js
var schedule = require("node-schedule");
var rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
//rule.minute = 40;
rule.second = 10;
var jj = schedule.scheduleJob(rule, function(){
    console.log("execute jj");
});
```

Maybe you can find the answer from node modules.