# Google Cloud Node JS - Will all setTimeOuts be erased after each deploy?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, settimeout, scalability, gcloud

I just want to understand if the server is fully restarted (clean state) or if it manages to migrate some of the memory data that was running from last version.

I have heard of node apps having 10k - 100k timeouts concurrently. On every new version (*gcloud app deploy*) of my server, will I lose all the pending functions that were not executed and I would need to reschedule all of them?

Comment: I'm guessing this is related to your earlier question [Node Js Express . how to schedule task
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48432356/node-js-express-how-to-schedule-task) for which I already told you that you would have to save the timer data yourself if you want it persisted across a server restart.

Comment: Yes it is, I was just wondering if Google Cloud did some kind of memory management on its own

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A node.js server has no memory of its own from the previous time it was run.  So, if you want a server to retain some state from one time it's run until the next (like after a restart), then you have to maintain that state yourself in a persistent store and read that state back in when your server starts.

> will I lose all the pending functions that were not executed and I would need to reschedule all of them?

Yes, you will lose them all.  node.js does not persist timers itself.  You will need to persist them yourself or use a different mechanism that does the persistence for you.